# SOLR not loading contents to tridion website

Tags: search, solr

The Solr instance is using the default jetty web server and is in running condition through a scheduled job through Windows Task Scheduler.

The contenthub tiles on tridion websitesite retrieves data through SOLR which is currently not working.

steps taken:
The services Tridion Content Manager Search Host service and the Tridion Content Manager Search Indexer services are stopped and started. The server has been restarted. The scheduled task been restarted.

None of these helped to fix the issue.Any assistance would be of great help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the website SOLR instance ("contenthub tiles on tridion websitesite retrieves data through SOLR") related to the CMS' internal SOLR instance? They are different modules and should be on different servers. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: You're mixing environments and concepts. The "Tridion Content Manager Search Host service and the Tridion Content Manager Search Indexer" power search in the Content Manager Explorer, not on your website. You must have a different SOLR instance _somewhere_ in your Content Delivery Architecture that is used by your site's tiles.

Answer (score 9):

From your question it seems that you probably do not have the background of the application. The Content Hub is no term in the SDL Tridion and must be related to the project (I probably know which project is this). If it is told to you that the data is being fetched from the SOLR, it means it is not the Tridion's SOLR but must be a separate implementation - So you should not put focus on the Tridion's services. Also, Tridion does not have any scheduled task so it must be related to Application specific.

I hope this app must be using the SS4T framework (please confirm with that) and you should be trying following:

- In the Scheduled Job - verify the SOLR related task is running, The task is pointing to the right SOLR by checking in the parameter of the task
- Verify the SOLR is running (hit http://:8983/solr) - check in the jetty config if the port is set to 8983 or something else.
- Verify in the SOLR instance if you have the necessary and expected content already indexed
- Check the Logs of your application, services (I hope there is a Index and Search service - if it is then check for the search service log), windows event logs etc. and share them up

I hope this helps starting you up